# Android with Jsp

Tags: android, jsp

I try to connect android app to Jsp page.It requires ip address of my server.At present I hot core ip address,But now I want to do it in dynamically for that what i do in my android code? Pls help me.

```
 URL url = new URL("http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/Iplogin.jsp?ip="+et.getText().toString());
```

Instead of xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080 i need to give in from setting file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `SharedPreferences`. It's is easy to fetch the preference values and also easy to make a preference activity.

Your code would look like:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String host = prefs.getString("KEY_PREF_IPADR", "127.0.0.1");
int port = prefs.getInt("KEY_PREF_PORT", 8080);
URL url = new URL("http://"+host+":"+port+"/Iplogin.jsp?ip="+et.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by putting your IP address in a strings xml file and retreiving it with getString(id).

Comment: ok.tnx Mr.alex,In case I put my ip address in string.xml and i got my apk.After that i switch over my Jsp page to other server then where i edit Ip address in my apk?..

Comment: So you want to change the address in an already packaged application?

Comment: ya.If there any other option to give the IP in androidmanifest.xml or res folder?... else getString(id) is the only way means, can u pls give sample code..